# The website redirects me to the old URL

Tags: redirects, wordpress, refresh

I moved a [wordpress site](http://www.jurnalul24.ro) after a host to another host and I changed the field. I changed the links when I want to sign, I login, wait a few seconds and redirects me the old site. Where is this problem?

Comment: What field did you change? Did you change the database settings?

Comment: I have not changed anything, I just moved files and database in the new hosting and I just wiped the cache. Where to find code? I did not realize where he might be,  I mention that the site was not made by me, just mute it.

Comment: You did state in the question that you "changed the field" - which field?